# Route restriction in Laravel for selected role

Tags: php, laravel

I have a users table with two types of users: Vendor and Customer. Every thing is fine with login if vendor role is 1 redirect to vendor Dashboard and for customer role is 2 redirect to customer dashboard but after login how to prevent route to customer dashboard if logged as vendor and vice versa
**Controller for login depend on role:**

```
class CustomerLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:web');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('Customer.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>2], $request->remember)) {

            return redirect()->intended(route('customer.dashboard'));

        } elseif (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>1],$request->remember)) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('vendor.dashboard'));

        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
    }

}
```

**after login route controller:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function index()
{
    return view('index.customer.customerdashboard');
}

public function vendor()
{
    return view('index.vendor.vendordashboard');
}
```

Comment: You could use this package for role permission [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: This can be done by utilising Middleware.

Comment: any code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a middleware with

```
php artisan make:middleware PortectedVendorRoutesMiddleware
```

Then, in the `handle`  method of that file, add the logic to check for the user's role

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->role_id == 1) {
       return $next($request);
    }


    abort(404);
}
```

Now you need to protect your routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => App\Http\Middleware\ProtectVendorRoutesMiddleware::class], function () {

    // Your protected vendor routes here
});
```

Or since Laravel 5.5

```
Route::middleware([App\Http\Middleware\ProtectVendorRoutesMiddleware::class])->group(function () {

    // Your protected vendor routes here
});
```

Repeat the process for Customer routes.

Comment: after I protected route: 
Route::group(['middleware' => App\Http\Middleware\ProtectVendorRoutesMiddleware::class]. function () {

Route::get('/vendor/dashboard', 'HomeController@vendor')->name('vendor.dashboard');
});
I got error
Array to string conversion

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: didn't work I know its the . and changed before but still got error Class App\Http\Middleware\ProtectVendorRoutesMiddleware does not exist even I added it to Kernal but still got error

Comment: Thank you @Lioople   Solved after added to kernal 'authen'=>\App\Http\Middleware\Authen::class, 
and inside Authen middleware added ur code
and route:  Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen']], function () { #route }